# Migrate from Apple Photos to darktable

Tags: software, darktable, apple

all. Is there already a way to migrate from Apple Photos to darktable? I know it's possible to read from an Apple Photos database with AppleScript and that Lua has a Lua scripting API, so if there isn't already a way, I'll just make one! Thanks!

Comment: You may want to pay for iCloud+ for long enough to upload your library to Apples servers, and then download it to a folder either using Windows or MacOS.   At least windows will allow you to have a folder with "download when needed" links that you - when done- can tell Windows to download all of them.  This will take time and bandwidth though

Answer (score 0):

The Photo.app AppleScript dictionary is very limited so you won't be able to access all the EXIF and IPTC data of the originals, not even all apple specific fields, if I remember well. It might as well be easier to start from the original files in folders.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there isn't yet a tool or script which automagically imports the data from *Photos.app* into *DarkTable*.

You'll need knowledge of *SQLite* and of some internals of *DarkTable* and *Photos.app* to create such script.

*Photos.app* keeps all information relating to the imported photos and videos in the following folder: `Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database`.

The main data are stored in the file `Photos.sqlite`. This is a plain SQLite database (with lots of data).

When *Photos.app* is closed, you can read this file with a tool such as *DB Browser for SQLite.app* (free). If you're afraid of doing something wrong, you should create a copy of `Photos.sqlite` in another folder to be sure.

I expect the `Photos.sqlite` database scheme to evolve between major macOS versions. So you may have to update your script annually (when a new macOS version is released).